# Is there a way to use the ui slider in editor mode? the slider is not moving, can't change it's value in editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this code is working fine in runtime but i want to make it working also in editor mode.
what i want to do is to be able to move the slider change it's value in both runtime and editor mode.

in runtime it's working fine.

don't know what else to add described the problem.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ObjectManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectPrefab;
    public Slider slider;

    private int currentObjectCount = 0;
    private int targetObjectCount = 0;
    private float minSliderValue = 0f;
    private float maxSliderValue = 100f;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying)
        {
            slider.minValue = minSliderValue;
            slider.maxValue = maxSliderValue;
            slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnSliderValueChanged);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!Application.isPlaying)
        {
            if (Mathf.RoundToInt(slider.value) != targetObjectCount)
            {
                OnSliderValueChanged(Mathf.RoundToInt(slider.value));
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnSliderValueChanged(float value)
    {
        targetObjectCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(value);

        if (targetObjectCount > currentObjectCount)
        {
            int objectsToCreate = targetObjectCount - currentObjectCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToCreate; i++)
            {
                CreateObject();
            }
        }
        else if (targetObjectCount < currentObjectCount)
        {
            int objectsToDestroy = currentObjectCount - targetObjectCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToDestroy; i++)
            {
                DestroyObject();
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateObject()
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10f, 10f), Random.Range(-5f, 5f), Random.Range(-10f, 10f));
        Instantiate(objectPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        currentObjectCount++;
    }

    private void DestroyObject()
    {
        GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Object");

        if (objects.Length > 0)
        {
            GameObject objectToDestroy = objects[objects.Length - 1];
            DestroyImmediate(objectToDestroy);
            currentObjectCount--;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that in editor mode I can't change the slider value.

[image: slider at the bottom left. can't change it's value in editor mode.]

Answer (score 0):

As said the `GameView` is not interactive in edit mode, mainly because nothing is receiving and handling any input while you are not in playmode.

Simplest solution imho would be to simply adjust the value via the Inspector of the slider itself.

Alternatively you could make your custom component drive the slider value while in edit mode using something like e.g.

```
[ExecuteAlways]
public class ObjectManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const int MIN_AMOUNT = 0;
    private const int MAX_AMOUNT = 100;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject objectPrefab;
    [SerializeField] private Slider slider;

    [SerializeField] [Range(MIN_AMOUNT, MAX_AMOUNT)] private int targetCount;

    // Keep track of instances!
    [SerializeField] private List<GameObject> _instances = new();

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!Application.isPlaying) return;

        slider.wholeNumbers = true;
        slider.minValue = MIN_AMOUNT;
        slider.maxValue = MAX_AMOUNT;
        slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnSliderValueChanged);
        slider.value = targetCount;
    }

    // Called automatically whenever a value in the Inspector of this component is changed
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (slider != null)
        {
            slider.wholeNumbers = true;
            slider.minValue = MIN_AMOUNT;
            slider.maxValue = MAX_AMOUNT;

            // skips the onValueChanged event
            slider.SetValueWithoutNotify(targetCount);
        }
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying) return;

        if (slider == null) return;
        if (objectPrefab == null)
        {
            OnSliderValueChanged(0);
            return;
        }

        OnSliderValueChanged(slider.value);
    }
#endif

    private void OnSliderValueChanged(float value)
    {
        var newCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(value);

        targetCount = newCount;
        var currentCount = _instances.Count;

        for (var i = currentCount; i < targetCount; i++)
        {
            CreateObject();
        }

        for (var i = targetCount; i < currentCount; i++)
        {
            DestroyObject();
        }
    }

    private void CreateObject()
    {
        var position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10f, 10f), Random.Range(-5f, 5f), Random.Range(-10f, 10f));

        _instances.Add(Instantiate(objectPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity));

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
#endif
    }

    private void DestroyObject()
    {
        var lastIndex = _instances.Count - 1;
        var objectToDestroy = _instances[lastIndex];

        DestroyImmediate(objectToDestroy);

        _instances.RemoveAt(lastIndex);

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
#endif
    }
}
```